# C++ gradient function returning false value

Tags: c++

User will enter 4 different points and findSlope (function) will calculate the value for slope and return back the value to be cout in main function.

But when I ran the program, it had logic error for slope value. Any idea why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

float findSlope(float a,float b,float c,float d)
{
    return (d-b/c-a);
}   
int main()
{
    float slope,p1,q1,p2,q2;

    cout << "Enter x1: ";
    cin >> p1;
    cout << "Enter y1: ";
    cin >> q1;
    cout << "Enter x2: ";
    cin >> p2;
    cout << "Enter y2: ";
    cin >> q2;

    slope=findSlope(p1,q1,p2,q2);
    cout << "Point1" << "\t\tPoint2" << "\t\tSlope" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << p1 << "," << q1 << "\t" << p2 << "," << q2 << "\t" << slope << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong. What is your input, your actual and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: use meaningful variable names and do take into account operator precendence, then you should find the mistake

Comment: `(d-b/c-a);` this is not how to calculate a slope. Voting to close as typo

Comment: As a final bit of political correctness, could you use the term "gradient" rather than "slope"?

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm sorry but the question given to me was like that

Comment: @Shizu: I'm sure many people on this site would think I'm being a bit of an idiot mentioning it, but Slope is a derogatory term in some countries, and this is an international site. (And a nicely presented question by the way.)

Comment: @Bathsheba It's good (in terms of general awareness) that you mention it, but I don't think giving up technical terminology because a word happens to have negative connotations in entirely different contexts is the way to go. [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_ADC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `return (d-b/c-a);`

Please look at order of operations again. What you intended to calculate was `(d-b)/(c-a)`. Right now you are calculating `d - (b/c) - a`. This is a basic mathematical thing and your calculator would most likely give you the same output if you had tried to check this yourself.

Comment: Upped, but don't forget to check if `c` is not equal to `a` before taking the division.

Comment: oh god i know it will be dumb mistake, thank you so much!!

Comment: Also; don't forget to account for the denominator == 0!

Answer (score 3):

Your slope function has

```
return (d-b/c-a)
```

did you mean

```
return ((d-b)/(c-a))
```

Operator precedence will do the division first, without the brackets.